# Android - Viewpager and fragments, methods not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `ViewPager` with two `Fragments` which I instantiate in `onCreate` of my `FragmentActivity`.

```
private List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Frag_1.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Frag_2.class.getName()));
    this.vPagerAdapter = new Adapt(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
    vPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vPager.setAdapter(vPagerAdapter);
```

My second `Fragment` has a method inside that I call to update my `ListView` - `refreshList()`:

```
public class Frag_2 extends Fragment {

    private ListView list;
    private ArrayList<data> data;
    private boolean firstCreation=true;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(false);
    }   

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lst);
        //this.setRetainInstance(true);
        return view;
    }


    public void refreshList(ArrayList <data> data){
        if(data!=null){
            ArrayAdapter<data> adapter = new Item_data_adapter(getActivity(),data);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);}
    }
}
```

Called from my `FragmentActivity`

```
//Something
Frag_2 fr = (Frag_2) vPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
if (fr.getView() != null) {
    fr.refreshList(data);
}
```

It works fine until I change the orientation of the screen. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was searching for hours and I didn't find a solution or a good explanation, the `FragmentActivity` is created only one time and the `Fragments` are attached to it but the `Fragments` recreate on configuration changes.
Now, when the orientation changes I don't get the `View` from `onCreate`so when I try  to get the `View` from the `Fragment` it returns null and my `refreshList()` method isn't called. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem and haven't found a solution. I'm starting to think there's a bug in `FragmentManager` or something else considering we're both experiencing this.

Comment: what about your xml layout? this isn't a problem for static fragments declared in activity's layout but this isn't the case for dynamic fragments

Comment: @zipc Both @DLock and I are using `ViewPager`. You don't write `Fragments` in your XML in that case.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This question was asked 3 years ago, any update on this? I'm considering fixing my Activity to portrait because I'm tired of Android and it's undocumented fragment usage. I havent found anything on this and even though I retain my fragments Android still recreates the views then attaches the Activity again yet after flipping a page the fragment will have isAlive() as false. Does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem this way:
In the onCreate of the FragmentActivity

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            frag1 = (frag_1) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, frag_1.class.getName());
            frag2 = (frag_2) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, frag_2.class.getName());
        }
        else{
            frag1 = (frag_1) Fragment.instantiate(this,frag_1.class.getName());
            frag2 = (frag_2) Fragment.instantiate(this,frag_2.class.getName());
        }
        fragments.add(frag1);
        fragments.add(frag2);


protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, frag_1.class.getName(), frag1);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, frag_2.class.getName(), frag2);
    }
```

Maybe it's not the best solution in the universe, but it looks like it works...

Comment: This does work, also adjusting the `configChanges` in the Manifest works, but I don't think these are solid solutions. I suppose this way would work in the case that you have one or two `Fragments`, but I actually have five that are being effected by this. I'm glad it works for you though.

Answer (score 0):

When u want to refresh the List do something like this :

```
public void setView() {
    Frag_2 fr = (Frag_2) vPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fr).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fr).commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a dynamic fragment, you need to test first to prevent creating a second instance of a fragment.

To test whether the system is re-creating the activity, check whether the Bundle argument passed to your activity’s
`onCreate()` is `null`.

If it is non-`null`, the system is re-creating the activity. In this case, the activity automatically re-instantiates existing
fragments.

If it's `null` you can safely instantiate your dynamic fragment. For example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ...
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
  // Or: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

The `Fragment` class supports the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method (but not the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method) in much the same way as the Activity class.

- The default implementation saves the state of all the fragment’s views that have IDs.
- You can override this method to store additional fragment state information.
- If the system is re-creating the fragment from a previous saved state, it provides a reference to the `Bundle` containing that state to the `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, and `onActivityCreated()` methods; otherwise, the
  argument is set to `null`.

If you want a detailed info, [here's](http://marakana.com/s/android_fragments_for_all,1099/index.html) a good talk by Ken Jones of Marakana

Comment: This answer isn't relevant to the question. @DLock and I are not using `FragmentTransaction`, or static `Fragments` in our XML. We're using `ViewPager`, which calls for a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.